# Interpret hex string as hex bytes for sha256 in bash

Tags: bash, hex, sha256

Let's say I have a hex string

```
6c64f463a38c670e5622f58ceccad23d8b9db5c9fc2a1717fc50015325b4764a
```

When I use `sha256sum` or `openssl dgst -sha256` I get this value:

```
52ad0981ad75e06084153fbe6d6e9363846b1cf14c9a84876d3504b957941fac
```

the problem here is that `sha256sum` thinks that this is text and therefor translates it into byte array which represents ASCII table, but I want it to calculate hash as it was a byte array.

For example this [service](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) can distinguish text format and hex format, so I get the right value:

```
4be5da7c50b521edb623936920044b1c546d3c38815ccc61c80b20fe171ff4cd
```

My actual question is:

- Is there a way to calculate hash from byte string as if it is a hex byte array in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert hex to binary and then use sha256sum:

```
echo -n '6c64f463a38c670e5622f58ceccad23d8b9db5c9fc2a1717fc50015325b4764a' \
| xxd -r -p \
| sha256sum \
| cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Output:

```
4be5da7c50b521edb623936920044b1c546d3c38815ccc61c80b20fe171ff4cd
```

See: [convert a hex string to binary and send with netcat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82561/74329)